# How can I use CSS animation in firefox?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the following code which is working fine on Chrome but not on Firefox. I want to know if something is going wrong in my code as the animation is totally different in this two browsers. As on Chrome the animation is smooth and the frames are fading nice. But on Firefox everything seem to be mess as there the animation seem to be cutted off.

```
#banner img {
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

#top {
  -moz-animation-name: bannerFadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-name: bannerFadeInOut;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
    <img class="back" id="back" src="frames/frame_1.jpg"/>
    <img class="top" id="top" src="frames/frame_2.jpg"/>
    <img id="logo1" type="image/svg+xml" src="" />                                              
    <div class="border" id="border"></div>
    <img id="cta" src="frames/title.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Include your HTML as well. For modern browsers, you need not use the prefixes though.

Comment: What do you mean it's cut off? And like Manoj says, there's no need to use moz prefixes. Firefox hasn't needed those for animation since 5.0, which is years ago.

Comment: for example if your animation frame has 5 seconds and it get a strong change at 3 seconds with almost no fading

Comment: What happens if you remove the -moz specific things?

Comment: is still same without any changes

Comment: It works fine for me in firefox with all the css and html you supplied. The fading of the #top image is identical to chrome.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9zo5me5L/ try this

Comment: there no problems in your code. upgrade your browser if you are using very old version of firefox..

Comment: Actually was. But I fixed it by adding position absolute on #top